# Parse regular expression from named group

Tags: python, regex

Here's a sample expression I'm working with `/api/(?P<version>v[0-9]+)/endpoint`.

I would like to do two things:

1. Get the named groups, i.e. `version`
2. For the named groups, get the expression associated with it, i.e. `v[0-9]+`

The first part can be grabbed from the compiled regex:

```
>>> r = re.compile('/api/(?P<version>v[0-9]+)/endpoint')
>>> r.groupindex 
{'version': 1}
```

I'm wondering if there's anything that will allow me to grab the expression from the parsed 'version' group, for example.

Comment: I don't think there is a re method to do that.

Comment: I suppose you could use regex to parse your regex?

Comment: @vaultah: Why not, but it's not possible with the re module.

Comment: @vaultah right - that's the only path I'm seeing, but I feel like there's got to be a way..

Comment: @NirvanaTikku nope - it's not possible using the builtin `re` module

Comment: The best you can do is build a look up of group name -> regex (either as a `dict` or `OrderedDict`... then build your regex from that... then look back into that based on group name to get the associated regex

Answer (score 2):

You can create a basic class that takes a template string, some parameters that are filled in by kwargs (or a dictionary), then proxy all other attribute access to a compiled regex object, eg:

```
import re

class myre(object):
    def __init__(self, template, *args, **kwargs):
        self.expressions = dict(kwargs)
        subs = {k: '(?P<{}>{})'.format(k, v) for k, v in self.expressions.items()}
        self.rx = re.compile(template.format(**subs), *args)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.rx, name)
```

Then use as follows:

```
r = myre('/api/{version}/endpoint', version='v[0-9]+')
print r.expressions['version'] # get expression for named group
# v[0-9]+

print list(r.expressions) # get list of named groups
# ['version']

# match as normal
print r.match('/api/v5/endpoint').group('version')
# v5
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement this yourself. For example:

```
group = {'version': 'v[0-9]+'}
r = re.compile('/api/(?P<{}>{})/endpoint'.format('version', group['version']))
```

Later you can map the group name `version` back to its regex `v[0-9]+`